# Why do I have two bluetooth services running?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I don't know why I've got what looks like two different bluetooth managers running. 
From the details, it appears that both `blueman` and `bluez` are active.

Are both of these necessary, or can I remove one of them?

Here are the running processes:

```
$ pgrep -fl blue
1155 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
3624 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
```

And the packages they apparently derive from:

```
$ dpkg -S  blueman-applet
blueman: /usr/share/dbus-1/services/blueman-applet.service
blueman: /usr/share/man/man1/blueman-applet.1.gz
blueman: /usr/bin/blueman-applet
$ dpkg -S  bluetoothd
bluez: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
bluez: /usr/share/man/man8/bluetoothd.8.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that blueman was installed (redundantly) when I added one of the several alternate desktop managers or environments (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.).

More importantly, I was able to remove all of the blueman packages, and everything still functions.  On the upgrade to 12.10, I didn't have any issues with it re-appearing.